# sql 2008 add sequential number

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I have a table with a primary key column ID, which needs to sequentially increase when a new record is inserted into the DB. (ie: 1,2,3,...)

Is there an option for the DB that I can set to do that automatically?

If not then what is the syntax to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the table with an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column, it will be done automatically for you;

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  val VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c');

SELECT * FROM test;

id   val
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

[An SQLfiddle showing it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af149/1).

Comment: Is it possible to change the PK column of an already created table, or do I need to drop/recreate?

Comment: @sd_dracula I don't think it's possible (still) in SQL server with just an alter table, but [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/) describes how to do it manually (but rather painfully).

Comment: Actually I was able to enable it in the SQL MGMT Studio, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need the identity property msdn docs explain it's usage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx